# MySQL fulltext search returns duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, full-text-search

I wrote codes to search for a keyword from different tables. This is my code :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT rest.*,
MATCH(rest.resname, rest.address) AGAINST(:keyword) as a,
MATCH(cuisine.cuisine) AGAINST(:keyword) as b,
MATCH(recc.recc) AGAINST(:keyword) as c,
MATCH(emenu.menu, emenu.menudesc) AGAINST(:keyword) as d,
MATCH(facilities.fac) AGAINST(:keyword) as e,
MATCH(serv.service) AGAINST(:keyword) as f
FROM rest
INNER JOIN cuisine ON rest.resID = cuisine.resID
INNER JOIN recc ON rest.resID = recc.resID
INNER JOIN emenu ON rest.resID = emenu.resID
INNER JOIN facilities ON rest.resID = facilities.resID
INNER JOIN serv ON rest.resID = serv.resID
WHERE
(
MATCH(rest.resname, rest.address) AGAINST(:keyword)
OR MATCH(cuisine.cuisine) AGAINST(:keyword)
OR MATCH(recc.recc) AGAINST(:keyword)
OR MATCH(emenu.menu, emenu.menudesc) AGAINST(:keyword)
OR MATCH(facilities.fac) AGAINST(:keyword)
OR MATCH(serv.service) AGAINST(:keyword)
)
AND (aktif = :aktif) AND (negeri = :negeri) ORDER BY resID DESC LIMIT :rowsperpage OFFSET :offset");

$stmt->bindValue(':keyword', $_GET["keyword"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':negeri', $negeri, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':aktif', $active, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':rowsperpage', (int) $rowsperpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':offset', (int) $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

There were 6 tables involved in this query.

Based on my thoughts, I really thinks if there are 2 same tags in a different table, it will return 2 results.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: why don't you list all the fields in only one match?

Comment: nevertheless, duplication is rather coming from joins, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use GROUP BY you main table id so it doesn't returns duplicate rows.
You can see a basic example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)